# CSS background inline SVG image not rendered when launching website locally

Tags: css, font-awesome, rollupjs, inline-svg

In [this project](https://github.com/wo-ist-markt/wo-ist-markt.github.io/pull/363) I am trying to replace [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com) with inline SVG icons.
The following CSS describes a menu toggle button as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Correctly rendered menu button]

```css
#btnToggleHeader {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.1em;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;

    /* The styling matches that of the select2 dropdown box */
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}

#btnToggleHeader:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#btnToggleHeader::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' width='1em' height='1em' style='-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet' viewBox='0 0 15 15'%3E%3Cg fill='none'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M1.5 3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h12a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-12zM1 7.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h12a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-12a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h12a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-12a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z' fill='%23626262'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 1px;
}
```

The button is [shown correctly](https://deploy-preview-363--wo-ist-markt.netlify.app) when I let Netlify deploy a snapshot of the website via [rollup.js](https://www.rollupjs.org).

When I launch the website locally by running

```sh
$ npm run build
$ python3 -m http.server
```

then the menu toggle button does **not** show up correctly as depicted in the following screenshot:

[image: Broken menu button]

Why does the icon behave different?

Comment: It seems browser related issue

Comment: The icon is showing up OK when I run the code locally. What do you see in your browser devtools inspect facility in terms of the CSS that is being applied? Is any CSS there? If so the icon should show on hovering it in the dev tools.

Comment: It looks like a caching problem. I reloaded the browser yet another time. Now the icon shows up correctly. You are welcome to convert your comment into an answer. Thank you!